# Does ground conduct heat?

Tags: heat-transfer

Does ground conduct heat or it acts like an insulator ? If yes then whats the conduction co-efficient or convection co-efficient ( in terms of convection heat transfer ) ?

Comment: How do you define a rate of conduction in terms of convection heat transfer? The ground does conduct heat - that is how some heat pumps source the energy they put into buildings... and how some ventilation systems cool hot air before it gets into the dwelling...

Comment: Yes the ground does conduct heat. Everything does that's not a vacuum. The ground in general is a pretty good insulator though. I have no numerical values for you though.

Comment: The co-efficient will depend on the type of ground & its nature: rock or soil, the compaction of the soil, moisture content, minerals within the soil or rock matrix - is it sandy, clayey, granitic, basaltic, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.geothermal-energy.org/pdf/IGAstandard/WGC/2010/2952.pdf) is a paper on measuring soil thermal conductivity, with quite a few values.  As noted by Fred, the value depends on the soil composition and moisture content.  It varies over quite a range, with values in this paper ranging from 0.15 to 5.03 W/m K.  Depending on the type of soil, the actual conductivity may be outside this range.